# PostgreSQL. Full-text search performance

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

all!
I have a table created in PostgreSQL 9.3 that contains about 24 millions records with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE jtest
(
  recordid uuid NOT NULL,
  details json,
  tsv tsvector,
  CONSTRAINT jtest_pkey PRIMARY KEY (recordid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Column tsv filled by trigger on the grounds of json contents:
to_tsvector('english', json_extract_path_text(details, 'info').

Field info in json structure have similar content. For example, "Milk from manufacturer one", "Milk from another two". There are about 1 million records that contains "milk".

If i use the following query:

> select recordid from jtest where tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', 'milk');

and dont use any index on tsv column, that query takes about 250 seconds. If i create gin index on tsv field then that query takes about 200 seconds.

Is there a possibility to increase performance?

Comment: Why is someone searching for milk if it's in every record?

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in the question:

> There are about 1 million records that contains "milk".

Index or not, you still need to retrieve that million rows. Also note that if a million means most rows, Postgres will ignore the index entirely and seq scan the entire table.

The index will help if you change the query to:

```
select recordid from jtest where tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', 'rare string');
```